# How to publish a Visual Studio project with script

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf

is someone knows how to publish a Visual Studio project by script which will do the equivalent of Right-click on the Web or WCF project and selecting "Publish..."?

[image: Publish]

**I don't want to deploy files on IIS!** I want only create files before copying it on IIS.
I tried to find it everywhere without success.

For Web project I can copy files from build folder, but for WCF how can I create automatically `web.config` and `.scv` files?

Comment: You can use [WCF Service Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-service-publishing), and when you click Publish, Visual Studio will deploy the application to the specified target location and copy the Web.config, .svc, and assembly files to the target directory.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not found any solution to my problem. It says :
"Open a service project, select Build > Publish <Project Name> from the main menu, or right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click Publish." But that's I want to avoid and want do that by a script.